# how do I make vscode terminal window clear previous spring boot output automatically?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I've managed to setup VS Code on my win10 with [Extension Pack for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack) and
[Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) I also enabled "clear previous output"

[image]

each time I right click and "Run Java",

[image]

VS code dump the output on the terminal window cumulatively.

[image]

the red rectangle indicates the first output and the blue the 2nd.

which means vscode doesn't clear the output before new run, and then I tried another option

[image]

which works for the simple pojo project.

However, when I run the [spring boot](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-rest-service) project, the terminal window keeps part of the logging anyway,

[image]

how do I make vscode clear all the previous spring boot output automatically as it does for pojo projects?

PS:

I also tried this task config which doesn't work either.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "mainClass": "com.example.mongo.MongoApplication",
            "targetPath": "${workspaceFolder}/${workspaceFolderBasename}.jar",
            "elements": [
                "${compileOutput}",
                "${dependencies}"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "label": "java: exportjar:mongo",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "presentation": {
                "clear": true // <-- this line
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Tries: (1) In `settings.json` add the line `"code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,` (2) Add a `clear` presentation option to a specific task (see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53180094/165358).

Comment: @harrymc Thank you. I tried those and updated my OP.

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69454188/165358).

Comment: @harrymc Thank you. it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution, published recently on
[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69048047),
is to modify `settings.json` so it looks like this:

```
{
    "editor.fontSize": 17,
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "PowerShell": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
        "args": ["-noLogo"]
        }
    },
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell"
}
```

If this doesn't work either (in addition to the other suggestions below
the post), then the basic problem is that
`"code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true` works well in the OUTPUT panel,
but does not work in the terminal.

A feature request was submitted for it at :
[Add code-runner.clearPrevious for terminal tab #832](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/832).
You may upvote it, which is basically your last option.